# Postgres function to delete old rows and return deleted rows

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I want to write a function to delete old rows in table Offers and then return the deleted rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delOldOffers() RETURNS void AS $$
DELETE FROM "public"."Offers"
 WHERE created_at < now() - interval '7 days'

$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

I wrote the above function but I am not sure how I can return rows that where deleted? If anyone can help that would be really great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your function to return a table (or setof) and use the returning clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deloldoffers(p_num_days integer) 
  RETURNS setof offers 
AS $$
  DELETE FROM Offers
  WHERE created_at < current_timestamp - make_interval(days => p_num_days)
  returning *;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

To use it, you need to select "from" it:

```
select *
from deloldoffers(10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Can I do something similar for update also to get the updated rows back -                                                                                                                
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateOldoffers(p_num_days integer) 
  RETURNS setof offers 
AS $$
 UPDATE  "public"."Offers"
    SET active = 'false'
 WHERE created_at  < current_timestamp - make_interval(days => p_num_days)
  returning *;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;